# Print label with barcode delphi console

Tags: delphi, console, label

I have a console application in Delphi and I have to print a label with a barcode.
How would I do that? Create a print service? Or would I use a `QuickReport`?

The application is to run in telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Printers, Graphics;
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  try
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmp.Width := 400;
      bmp.Height := 400;
      // your Barcode - Code here
      bmp.Canvas.Ellipse(10,10,300,300);
      Printer.BeginDoc;
      Printer.Canvas.Draw(10,10,bmp);
      Printer.EndDoc;
    finally
      bmp.Free;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: How can I include the value to be printed? And what code symbology, 2of5?Today I take a memo and print it line by line would be equal?
My printing code
`(Procedure ImprimirMemo(Memo: TStrings; TamanhoFonte: Integer; PrinterIndex: Integer);
Var
  I: integer;
  F: Text;
Begin
  { Usa na impressora a mesma fonte do memo }

  Printer.PrinterIndex := PrinterIndex;
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := TamanhoFonte;

  AssignPrn(F);
  Rewrite(F);
  Try
    For I := 0 To Memo.Count - 1 Do
      WriteLn(F, Memo[I]);
  Finally
    CloseFile(F);
  End;
End;)`

Comment: This is fine, only I'd guess that what @user is looking for is that part of your program which is the comment

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with label printers that connect to a serial port, and most of them know how to print a barcode, all you need to do is tell them where, what code and which symbiology. Depending of the brand and type of the label printer, your manual should tell you how to make the printer print a label. For example: [Epson ESC](http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf)(pdf) page C-195 or [datamax-oneil's Compact4](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/file.cfm/540340_lp_prog.pdf?contentID=4973)(pdf) page 15

Answer (score 0):

We use the `TppDBBarcode` component from ReportBuilder to print barcodes.